# Rails order method; column named :order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model Exercises and it has columns of :circuit and :order (among others). In a view, I am trying to order the Exercises first by :circuit and then by :order. When I use the following:

```
@schedule.exercises.order(:circuit).each do |exercise|
```

it works as expected. However, when I try to add the :order column:

```
@schedule.exercises.order(:circuit, :order).each do |exercise|
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "order": syntax error: SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises"  WHERE "exercises"."schedule_id" = 1 ORDER BY circuit, order
```

The same error also occurs when I pass the :order column alone:

```
@schedule.exercises.order(:order).each do |exercise|

SQLite3::SQLException: near "order": syntax error: SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises"  WHERE "exercises"."schedule_id" = 1 ORDER BY order
```

I'm assuming that this is because the column name (:order) is the same as the SQL method name (`order`). I'm wondering if there's any way around this other than changing my column heading?

Thanks,
Stuart

Comment: Probably just easier to change the name of the column to sort rather than using a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the column name is the only sensible option out of this. Change it to something like "position".

Comment: Thanks - I guess I know what I'm doing this evening. Live and learn.

Comment: I lol'd cause I am here because I have a column called 'position' that, due to business logic, I wanted to change to 'order'... I am thinking 'sequence' could work as an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to try and do this you could write a find by sql query and escape the col name with back quotes like

```
ModelName.find_by_sql(SELECT * FROM ModelName ORDER BY '`order`')
```

But I would say you should just change the column name

Comment: Your single quotes are in the wrong place and you should use double quotes to quote identifiers (such as column names) in SQL, backticks are a MySQL-ism that SQLite unfortunately supports.

Comment: All true, twas more of an rough example of how backquotes could be used not production code. Blatantly the answer is to change the column name. But at least i have one more reason not to use SQLite. Not that I needed one

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue, but specifying table name in order clause it works.

```
@schedule.exercises.order("exercises.circuit ASC, exercises.order ASC").each do |exercise|
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "reorder" instead of "order"